# Can't install react-transition-group

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Trying to install `react-transition-group` but get the following error

```
npm install react-transition-group@1.x --save


npm ERR! peerinvalid The package react@15.6.1 does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer react-bootstrap@0.31.0 wants react@^0.14.9 || >=15.3.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer react-dom@15.6.1 wants react@^15.6.1
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer react-fontawesome@1.6.1 wants react@>=0.12.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer react-redux@5.0.5 wants react@^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0-0 || ^16.0.0-0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer react-router@4.1.1 wants react@^15
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer react-router-dom@4.1.1 wants react@^15
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer react-simple-currency@1.0.15 wants react@^0.14.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer react-transition-group@1.2.0 wants react@^15.0.0
```

The current dependencies in packages.json are

```
 "dependencies": {
    "accounting": "0.4.1",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.20.0",
    "css-loader": "0.28.2",
    "history": "4.6.1",
    "immutable": "3.8.1",
    "jsonapi-serializer": "3.5.3",
    "numeral": "2.0.6",
    "prop-types": "15.5.10",
    "react": "^15.3.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "0.31.0",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.1",
    "react-fontawesome": "1.6.1",
    "react-redux": "5.0.5",
    "react-router": "4.1.1",
    "react-router-dom": "4.1.1",
    "redux": "3.6.0",
    "sprintf-js": "1.1.1",
    "style-loader": "0.18.1",
    "superagent": "3.5.2",
    "superagent-no-cache": "0.1.1",
    "zpad": "0.5.0"
  },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Updated npm `npm install npm -g`
2. Cleared cache: `npm cache clear`
3. Removed node_modules `rm -rf node_modules`
4. Reinstalled node_modules, `npm install`.

Comment: If you are using the latest version of npm, then you can't do ```npm cache clear```. As of npm@5, the npm cache self-heals from corruption issues and data extracted from the cache is guaranteed to be valid. If you want to make sure everything is consistent, use 'npm cache verify' instead.

Comment: Had to use --force with `npm cache clear` as it was throwing some error. Rest works fine.

Answer (score -1):

just execute the command:
`npm install react-transition-group`

and it will work.

Comment: Please consider providing some additional context to this answer so that it is clearer why this answer is correct.